# How to get exact id from MonogoDb using Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have created a spring boot project with mongodb , when i insert data into collection it get inserted but when i try to fetch from mongodb it returns the  id as follows

```
"id": {
            "timestamp": 1586793129,
            "counter": 877082,
            "date": "2020-04-13T15:52:09.000+0000",
            "time": 1586793129000,
            "machineIdentifier": 1589527,
            "processIdentifier": 29810,
            "timeSecond": 1586793129
        },
```

How get the exact id from the mongoDB ?

else how generate id from the respective fields

Answer (score 0):

You need serialization. So easy way is to add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0.rc1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you need to add following method in main class.

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer customizer()
{
    return builder -> builder.serializerByType(ObjectId.class,new ToStringSerializer());
}
```

That's all, Have fun

Comment: Thank you @varman for the answer . i am new to spring  boot framework. so  can i get the file name for adding  the dependancy

Comment: You just need to copy the above dependency and paste into pom.xml

Comment: What about the  `customizer()` method  . can i  get the file name for adding  the method

Comment: You don't worry about that method. Its a `@Bean`. You don't need to call that method anywhere. This method automatically converts extended id to String. It helps other way around also

Comment: I am asking about declaration  of the   `customizer()`

Comment: No i don't get any error. i just looking  for the file name for declaring this method

Comment: You need to add in the main class

Comment: Does this help you?